# Get sum of certain select boxes javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp-classic

I am so behind in the coding i am a pure novice but not dumb.I work with Dreamweaver love the program i also like the fact it shows you errors and hints to fix. I am creating a score card for a golf site where you will use drop down select boxes to pick a score for each of the 18 holes you played. example for a few

```
<form action="" method="post" id="postscore"> 
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4">
            <tr class="LeaderBoardTopColum">
              <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="9%">1</td>
              <td width="9%">2</td>
              <td width="9%">3</td>
              <td width="9%">4</td>
              <td width="9%">5</td>
              <td width="9%">6</td>
              <td width="9%">7</td>
              <td width="9%">8</td>
              <td width="9%">9</td>
              <td width="9%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>


<tr>
              <td>Front 9</td>
              <td>
              <select name="H1">       
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H2">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td>
                <select name="H3">   
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H4">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H5">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H6">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H7">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H8">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H9">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input2" value="0" id="total_row_1" /></td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="LeaderBoardTopColum">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

<tr>
              <td>Back 9</td>
              <td><select name="H10">
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H11">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H12"> 
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H13">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H41">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H15">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H16">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H17">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H18">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input2" value="0" id="total_row_2" /></td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="11"> </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
<!--assigned event to the form to call OnChangeFinal()--> 


         <input name="TotalPar" type="text" value="0" maxlength="2"/><!--The grand total appears here-->


<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What i would love to see is a Total for the F9 on Row 1 as a TEXT then Total for B9 on Row 2 as text and The entire 18 hole Total in a TEXT also IF the member changes his selection to make sure the Totals of the fields do to? and a hidden field where i will carry the total sum into my .ASP insert recordset. Please keep in mind i have other select list menus on this page BUT i do not want to add them in any of the totals i need.I have spent 3-4 days looking at snippets on this site some apps came close but always error me some how. Can anyone help? Thank you very much for yuor time

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('select[name^=H]').change(function()
{
  var sum = 0;
  var range = $(this).attr("name").length > 2 ? $(this).attr("name").slice(1,3) : $(this).attr("name").slice(1,2);
  if(range < 9)
  {
     $('select[name^=H]').each(function()
     {
         var range = $(this).attr("name").length > 2 ? $(this).attr("name").slice(1,3) : $(this).attr("name").slice(1,2);
         if(range <= 9)
          sum += parseInt($(this).val());
     });
     $('#total_row_1').val(sum);
  }
  else
  {

     $('select[name^=H]').each(function()
     {
         var range = $(this).attr("name").length > 2 ? $(this).attr("name").slice(1,3) : $(this).attr("name").slice(1,2);
         if(range > 9)
          sum += parseInt($(this).val());
     });

     $('#total_row_2').val(sum);
  }
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/10/

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, you can add an event so that when the user changes a selection a function is called, you can have the onChange event call the same function as long as the totals are adding from the same inputs:

```
<select name="H1" onChange="updateTotals();">
```

..
First, change your name="H1" to id="H1". Unless you are submitting the form, use id.

Next, change `<td>Front 9</td>` to `<td id="frontLabel">Front 9</td>` if thats where you want to update the total.

In your `<HTML><HEAD>` .. add:

```
<script>
  function updateTotals() {
    //read the values which need to be totaled
    var val1 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H1'));
    .. repeat for all...

    //add them up
    var total = val1 + val2 + ...;

    //update the results on your page
    var totalFieldElement = document.getElementById('frontLabel');
    totalFieldElement.textContent = "Front 9: " + total ; 
  }

function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Here is the complete code for the front 9,you can copy and paste to make changes for the back, [here it is so you can demo it on plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qjK6CWIXFzHnjE8dBc20?p=preview) also:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <script>

     function updateTotals() {

    //read the values which need to be totaled
    var val1 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H1'));
    var val2 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H2'));
    var val3 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H3'));
    var val4 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H4'));
    var val5 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H5'));
    var val6 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H6'));
    var val7 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H7'));
    var val8 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H8'));
    var val9 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H9'));

    //add them up
    var total = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6 + val7 + val8 + val9;

    //update the results on your page
    var totalFieldElement = document.getElementById('total_row_1');
    totalFieldElement.value = total ; 

  }

function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}

 </script>
  </head>

  <body>
<form action="" method="post" id="postscore"> 
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4">
            <tr class="LeaderBoardTopColum">
              <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="9%">1</td>
              <td width="9%">2</td>
              <td width="9%">3</td>
              <td width="9%">4</td>
              <td width="9%">5</td>
              <td width="9%">6</td>
              <td width="9%">7</td>
              <td width="9%">8</td>
              <td width="9%">9</td>
              <td width="9%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>


<tr>
              <td >Front 9</td>
              <td>
              <select onChange="updateTotals();" id="H1">       
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select onChange="updateTotals();" id="H2">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td>
                <select onChange="updateTotals();" id="H3">   
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select onChange="updateTotals();" id="H4">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select onChange="updateTotals();"  id="H5">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select onChange="updateTotals();"  id="H6">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select onChange="updateTotals();"  id="H7">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select onChange="updateTotals();"  id="H8">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select  onChange="updateTotals();" id="H9">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input2" value="0" id="total_row_1" /></td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="LeaderBoardTopColum">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

<tr>
              <td>Back 9</td>
              <td><select name="H10">
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H11">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H12"> 
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H13">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H41">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H15">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H16">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H17">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H18">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input2" value="0" id="total_row_2" /></td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="11"> </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
<!--assigned event to the form to call OnChangeFinal()--> 


         <input name="TotalPar" type="text" value="0" maxlength="2"/><!--The grand total appears here-->


<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
<script> updateTotals();</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thril -- I tried and tried and tried again i just could not get your script to work i did it many different ways the easy way here and still not working

Comment: <script>
  function updateTotals() {
    //read the values which need to be totaled
    var val1 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H1'));
 var val2 = parseInt(getSelectedText('H2'));
    //add them up
    var total = val1 + val2;

    //update the results on your page
    var totalFieldElement = document.getElementById('frontLabel');
    totalFieldElement.textContent = "Front 9: " + total ; 
  }

function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}
 </script>

Comment: <select name="H1" onChange="updateTotals();">       
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
    <td id="frontLabel">Front 9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <select name="H2" onChange="updateTotals();">       
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select> and <td id="frontLabel">Front 9</td>

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see it in action.  If you want to keep name="" you can do this, change getElementById to getElementsByName() in the second function and change back where i modified name= to id=

Comment: Sorry it has taken my this long to reply back the code is an absolute dream works to perfection my friend!! i thank you very much thril from all my heart!

Comment: Glad it worked! can you check my answer as accepted then?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').change(function () {
            updateTotals();
        });


        function updateTotals()
        {
            var szResult1=0;
            var szResult2=0;
            var szResult3 = 0;
            var szName = ""

            for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                {
                szName = "H" + i;

                value1 = $("select[name=" + szName + "]").val()
                szResult1 = szResult1 + parseInt(value1, 10);

                }

            for (i = 10; i <= 18; i++) {
                szName = "H" + i;
                value1 = $("select[name=" + szName + "]").val()
                szResult2 = szResult2 + parseInt(value1, 10);
            }

            szResult3 = szResult1 + szResult2;

            $('#total_row_1').val(szResult1);
            $('#total_row_2').val(szResult2)
            $('input[name=TotalPar]').val(szResult3)
        }

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" id="postscore"> 
<table width="99%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4">
            <tr class="LeaderBoardTopColum">
              <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="9%">1</td>
              <td width="9%">2</td>
              <td width="9%">3</td>
              <td width="9%">4</td>
              <td width="9%">5</td>
              <td width="9%">6</td>
              <td width="9%">7</td>
              <td width="9%">8</td>
              <td width="9%">9</td>
              <td width="9%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>


<tr>
              <td>Front 9</td>
              <td>
              <select name="H1">       
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H2">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td>
                <select name="H3">   
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H4">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H5">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H6">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H7">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H8">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H9">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input2" value="0" id="total_row_1" /></td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="LeaderBoardTopColum">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>10</td>
              <td>11</td>
              <td>12</td>
              <td>13</td>
              <td>14</td>
              <td>15</td>
              <td>16</td>
              <td>17</td>
              <td>18</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

<tr>
              <td>Back 9</td>
              <td><select name="H10">
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H11">
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H12"> 
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H13">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H14">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H15">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H16">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H17">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><select name="H18">        
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select></td>
              <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" class="input2" value="0" id="total_row_2" /></td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="11"> </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
<!--assigned event to the form to call OnChangeFinal()--> 


         <input name="TotalPar" type="text" value="0" maxlength="2"/><!--The grand total appears here-->


<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: changed "<td><select name="H41">"    to  "<td><select name="H14">"    in your code